# Changing UICollectionViewCell design on select

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` , Under that collection view i have **custom** `UICollectionViewCell` with  A Image view and A label. I am trying to change color of label text of selected  cell. But every time i am changing the color of label text, its changing in multiple cells . Can anyone help me with the issue?

The code i am using :

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *te =[self.smilyObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.wallPostMood =[te objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.wallPostMood);
    EffectsCollectionViewCell *efCell = (EffectsCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    efCell.title.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EffectsCollectionViewCell *efCell = (EffectsCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        efCell.title.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

I also have tried :

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *te =[self.smilyObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.wallPostMood =[te objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.wallPostMood);
    NSArray* visibleCellIndex = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems ;
    for(NSIndexPath * path in visibleCellIndex){
        EffectsCollectionViewCell *efCell = (EffectsCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:path];

        if([efCell.title.text isEqualToString:self.wallPostMood]){
//            NSLog(@"%@",efCell);
//            NSLog(@"got");
           efCell.title.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

        }else{
            efCell.title.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Does this happen when you scroll the colledtion view? You might try setting the color for each cell in the cellForItemAtIndexPath to the default gray color.

Comment: Since you are using a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, you could also override `setSelected:animated` in `EffectsCollectionViewCell`, and keep in your dataSource (or somewhere) which cells are selected?